# Using Case statement in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, case, where-clause

In my query I have the following condition

```
left Join Table2 on Table2.Id = Table1.Id and Table2.status in  ('Close', 'Open')
```

And the above condition gives me 2 extra rows because of the left join. I noticed that if I have only either Close or Open in the condition it returns the correct number of rows.

To fix that I was trying to write something like this

```
And  Table2.status = (Case Table2.status
                WHEN 'Open' Then 'Open'
                When 'Close' Then 'Close'   
                 End )
```

But this still returns 2 extra rows. Any suggestions on how to fix this??

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: What status are those 2 extra rows in?

Comment: change left join to inner join?

Comment: that's the point of the outer joins, to give you extra rows when needed. If you want an exact match, just do a normal join

Comment: I believe he wants a 0 or 1 match, but if there are more than 1 matches to truncate down to 1. An inner join would not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select *
from table1
    left join 
    (
         select id from table2 
         where status in ('open', 'close')
         group by id

    ) as table2
        on table1.id = table2.id
```

This seems pretty hacky, but I cannot seem to come up with something better at the moment. Otherwise, you could use a `DISTINCT`

```
select DISTINCT table1.*, table2.stuff
FROM Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2
        on Table2.Id = Table1.Id and Table2.status in  ('Close', 'Open')
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is the `DISTINCT` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.* FROM Table1 
     LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Id 
                      AND Table2.status in  ('Close', 'Open')
```